# Simple yes/no for restarting C# program using a do-while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while, restart

I can't figure out why my string *restart* changes to "NO" no matter what I enter at this point:

```
while (
  (restart != "YES") && (restart != "NO")
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
do
{
    //main part of program
    Console.Write("Do you wish to calculate another? (YES/NO) ");
    restart = Console.ReadLine();
    restart = qualified.ToUpper();
    while ((restart != "YES") && (restart != "NO"))   //????
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to calculate another? (YES/NO) ");
        restart = Console.ReadLine();
        restart = qualified.ToUpper();
    }
} while (restart == "YES");
```

Comment: You set restart as the console input, then you set it as the uppercase of some variable "qualified"..

Comment: `restart = qualified.ToUpper();` ?

Comment: Debug your code. Watch the values change. As `stuartd` points out, you throw away their input immediately. Had you gone through it step by step, you would have found this.

Answer (score 2):

`qualified.ToUpper()` is never assigned to, and so remains the same. And your `restart` variable is always assigned that same value regardless of what the user inputs. Just take that out and use:

```
do
{
    //main part of program
    Console.Write("Do you wish to calculate another? (YES/NO) ");
    restart = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    while ((restart != "YES") && (restart != "NO"))   //????
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to calculate another? (YES/NO) ");
        restart = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }
} while (restart == "YES");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following code:

```
restart = qualified.ToUpper();
```

Comment: Very embarrassed to say the least...  Coding when tired  is not a good idea.  Thanks for the fast response everyone.

Comment: Np. So please vote up